# Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400 on rest api call

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am hoping someone can tell me why I am getting a bad request when this executes

Here is my rest api code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/emailservices/*')
global class EmailInsert {

  @HttpPost 
  global static String addEmail(String fName, String fEmail, String pToAddress,
                                    String pSubject, String pTextBody, String cid) {
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(FromName=fName, FromAddress=fEmail, ToAddress=pToAddress,
  Subject=pSubject, TextBody=pTextBody, ParentId=cid, MessageDate=System.now(),
  Incoming=true, Status='0');
insert msg;

return msg.Id;
  }
}
```

And here is the method that is calling it

```
  @future(callout=true)
  private static void DoCallout(String cid, String subj, String tbody)
  {
Map<String, String> jinp = new Map<String, String>();
jinp.put('fname','Service');
jinp.put('fEmail','noreply@acme.com');
jinp.put('pToAddress', UserInfo.getUserEmail());
jinp.put('pSubject', subj);
jinp.put('pTextBody', tbody);
jinp.put('cid', cid);     

String jsonInput = JSON.serialize(jinp);
    system.debug('JSON String: ' + jsonInput);
    // Call the web service to insert into Email Message object
    Http http       = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

      req.
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint('https://<myinstance>.force.com/support/services/apexrest/emailservices');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(jsonInput);
    http.send(req);       
  }
```

When the call executes I end up with Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400 in the debug logs I have looked at the formatted JSON String and it looks good.

Any thoughts as to why this fails?

Comment: Are you trying to call rest webservice exposed in another Salesforce org?. Because if both classes are in same org, you can just call the method directly instead of using webservice.

Comment: can you post JSON String: Debug ?

Comment: You should be creating a Inner class and serializing the class, not building the string out like that btw https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#unique_1723316930

Comment: @EricSSH Thanks I changed the code to use a map object and JSON.serialize(). It definitely created a prettier JSON string but it still does not work

Comment: Is this an end point you built? are you authenticating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mismatch in post variable name and parameter in the Rest service. I posted it as fname and retrieved it as fName. The results that came back in the debug logs were very vague that simple "bad request"
I used SoapUI to post the request without apex and the results were much more detailed allowing me to figure out why it was a bad request

Comment: The reason for the bad request it the code throwing an error. SF does not do a good job with error responses thats for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call rest webservice exposed in another Salesforce org?. Because if both classes are in same org, you can just call the method directly instead of using webservice.

Also if you are trying to access webservice from a different salesforce org, you would need to authenticate against second org using Oauth

Also your end point looks wrong. Generally it will be like "https://rd-mevion.cs22.force.com/services/apexrest/emailservices" without support in between.

Checkout below post,
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099zbIAA

Comment: No it's all under the same org. A community user logged gets a new case page that generates emails. Apparently salesforce doesn't let community users add EmailMessage objects they are read only to them and this cannot be changed. I saw a solution from someone else that they solved it by using a rest api function to insert the email and attach it to the case. the support in the url is because that is part of the community name. If I don't put that I get service unavailable instead of bad request

Comment: Can u pls give a try adding token to request using below lines,
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());

Comment: I am setting the header to what I thought it had to be to pass the JSON string to the http request as you can see in the code I supplied. If I change the req.setHeader to what you show there I get a different error
System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `https://rd-mevion.cs22.force.com` in Remote Site Settings even though you might be calling from the same org

Comment: I had already done that and it made no difference